# Are there any instances in the Old Testament of a person receiving genuine visions, and then later turning to lies and fabricating visions?

Tags: biblical-basis, revelation, visions

There's an instance in the history of one church in particular where it's held that one man had genuine visions from God, but that at a later point in his life after having been excommunicated he continued receiving "visions". The members of this church will genuinely hold that his earlier visions were true and his later visions were false.

I'm curious if this sort of story has an precendence. Obviously the later lies of visions would normally put into question any of his previous visions, in my estimation - if he shows a proclivity about lieing about visions *now*, why would God reveal things to such a dishonest man earlier? If his visions previously **were** genuine, what could make a man capable of receiving genuine revelations turn into such a dishonest man?

I'm thinking there could perhaps be some clues in similar stories from the Old Testament (or in Christianity I suppose), so I'm searching for similar stories.

Comment: Can you provide references to primary sources about the story you allude to in the first paragraph?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I would like to avoid tainting the question with bias, since this is an active religion which many people feel strongly about, both for and against. If you want to PM me about it, I'd be happy to give you details in private.

Comment: I would recommend that you scope the question to that specific denomination, so that they can explain their beliefs and actions. This will also make the answers more objective because they can cite primary sources of that denomination and not have a bunch of different denominations all chiming in and creating a popularity contest.

Comment: @4castle there's a reason that I'm not asking that, and that is because I know what the result of that line of questions would be. I know what THEY think - they think his earlier visions are valid, and his later visions are not, and whatever argument they can think of to justify that, they will use, because that is the nature of apologetics - you start with your conclusion and work backwards.

Comment: So I'm curious in a non-denominational specific way if this has ever happened before.

Comment: Not sure why you interpret the falsehood in question to refer to human fabrication; perhaps they simply meant his later visions were demonic delusions (2 Corinthians 11:14). It is quite possible that, after having his initial, presumably divine visions, he fell into pride, thus providing satan with an opportunity for attack; after all, even prophets are only human. Which is probably why the term *spiritual discernment* is mentioned in several New Testament passages.

Comment: Ah, that's a possible spin, sure. Good idea. Of course the frustrating thing about that is that that's a way to just pick and choose whatever you like. You like his earlier visions? Well those ones are from God! You don't like his later ones? That's because they're from devils.

Comment: @TKoL: I understood the idea that you were trying to convey; it's just that, what I wrote is based on a theoretical (but nevertheless explicit) discussion about demonic delusion, from a book by a [nineteenth century Russian monk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignatius_Brianchaninov), wherein he argues that an inclination towards such experiences could (and does) lead there, even in situations where the original or initial miracles were indeed from God.

Comment: In my opinion that begs the question why God would use such a person for his revelations in the first place. If God deems a person worthy of revealing revelations through, then surely this person is worth *protecting* from such influences. Otherwise, his later corruption puts all the previous revelations into doubt, which... defeats the purpose of giving this person revelations in the first place.

Comment: Since we know God is incapable of foolish decisions, that leaves us with only two possibilities: either all of his revelations are true, or none are. That's my opinion, anyway. It seems far more likely to be one of those two than `"some are"`.

Comment: My question has been flagge as "opinion based", but I don't think it is. I'm asking for literal examples of this in the old testament, or in Christian history. It's not an opinion. Has this sort of thing happened before? That seems to me to be a question of fact, not opinion.

Comment: I marked the question as opinion-based because different denominations interpret scripture differently and they also disagree on whether God inspired various visions. Some Christians even doubt the inspiration of parts of the Bible. I personally believe that after the completion of Revelation, there have not been any more inspired visions from God. This question will attract opinions.

Comment: That's a pretty weak reason to close the question. All questions "will attract opinions" by that logic, do you vote to close all questions? I look at your history of answers and questions and see questions that will "attract opinions" because people "interpret scripture differently".

Comment: Good questions on this site are usually scoped to ask about the beliefs of a specific denomination. Regardless of whether other people disagree with that denomination, those answers are objectively the beliefs of that denomination, and so it's not opinion-based. That's why I suggested to scope to that one denomination which prompted your question, but really you could scope to any denomination you want.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the lie in the mouth of a prophet comes from the Lord:

> But Micaiah said, “As the LORD lives, what the LORD says to me, that I will speak.” 
> And when he had come to the king, the king said to him, “Micaiah, shall we go to Ramoth-gilead to battle, or shall we refrain?” **And he answered him, “Go up and triumph; the LORD will give it into the hand of the king.”** But the king said to him, “How many times shall I make you swear that you speak to me nothing but the truth in the name of the LORD?” And he said, “I saw all Israel scattered on the mountains, as sheep that have no shepherd. And the LORD said, ‘These have no master; let each return to his home in peace.’” And the king of Israel said to Jehoshaphat, “Did I not tell you that he would not prophesy good concerning me, but evil?”And Micaiah said, “Therefore hear the word of the LORD: I saw the LORD sitting on his throne, and all the host of heaven standing beside him on his right hand and on his left; and the LORD said, ‘Who will entice Ahab, that he may go up and fall at Ramoth-gilead?’ And one said one thing, and another said another. Then a spirit came forward and stood before the LORD, saying, ‘I will entice him.’ And the LORD said to him, ‘By what means?’ And he said, ‘I will go out, and will be a lying spirit in the mouth of all his prophets.’ And he said, ‘You are to entice him, and you shall succeed; go out and do so.’ Now therefore behold, the LORD has put a lying spirit in the mouth of all these your prophets; the LORD has declared disaster for you.”

- 1 Kings 22:14-23

Answer (score 0):

The name of Jonah comes to mind. He didn't receive a vision, but God told Jonah,

> Jonah1:2 Arise, go to Nineveh, that great city, and cry against it;
> for their wickedness is come up before me. (also 3:2).

So when Jonah finally got there he proclaimed,

> 3:4 And Jonah began to enter into the city a day's journey, and he
> cried, and said, Yet forty days, and Nineveh shall be overthrown.

Maybe he wasn’t lying, but he didn’t get the story straight either. He spoke presumptuously. (Deu 18:22) Anyway, the warning worked and the people repented.

> 3:10 And God saw their works, that they turned from their evil way;
> and God repented of the evil, that he had said that he would do unto
> them; and he did it not.

It says that God repented of what He said, but I don’t find 40 days anywhere. What’s going on here? Anyway, Jonah wasn’t happy.

> 4: But it displeased Jonah exceedingly, and he was very angry.2 And he
> prayed unto the Lord, and said, I pray thee, O Lord, was not this my
> saying, when I was yet in my country? Therefore I fled before unto
> Tarshish: for I knew that thou art a gracious God, and merciful, slow
> to anger, and of great kindness, and repentest thee of the evil.3
> Therefore now, O Lord, take, I beseech thee, my life from me; for it
> is better for me to die than to live.

It would seem Deu 18:22 applies. That’s the way I understand it.
A more direct example of false prophets is Hananiah.

> Jer 28:10 Then Hananiah the prophet took the yoke from off the prophet
> Jeremiah's neck, and brake it.11 And Hananiah spake in the presence of
> all the people, saying, Thus saith the Lord; Even so will I break the
> yoke of Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon from the neck of all nations
> within the space of two full years. And the prophet Jeremiah went his
> way.12 Then the word of the Lord came unto Jeremiah the prophet, after
> that Hananiah the prophet had broken the yoke from off the neck of the
> prophet Jeremiah, saying,13 Go and tell Hananiah, saying, Thus saith
> the Lord; Thou hast broken the yokes of wood; but thou shalt make for
> them yokes of iron. 14 For thus saith the Lord of hosts, the God of
> Israel; I have put a yoke of iron upon the neck of all these nations,
> that they may serve Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon; and they shall
> serve him: and I have given him the beasts of the field also.15 Then
> said the prophet Jeremiah unto Hananiah the prophet, Hear now,
> Hananiah; The Lord hath not sent thee; but **thou makest this people to
> trust in a lie.**16 Therefore thus saith the Lord; Behold, I will cast
> thee from off the face of the earth: this year thou shalt die, because
> thou hast taught rebellion against the Lord.17 **So Hananiah the prophet
> died the same year in the seventh month**.

Jeremiah had received God's message, but Hananiah contradicted it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the argument that Jonah lied about his vision. In fact, verse 40 says `"When the true God saw what they did, how they had turned back from their evil ways,f he reconsidered* the calamity that he said he would bring on them, and he did not bring it."` So... did Jonah lie about it?

Comment: I don't have the context for what Jonah wasn't happy about or why he wasn't happy.

Comment: Did Hananiah transition from a true prophet to a false prophet? Or was he/she just a false prophet the whole time?

Comment: Like I said, maybe he didn't lie. I think he just talked presumptuously. (Deu 18:22)

Comment: I guess he just felt humiliated for being wrong. Maybe he realized he was a false prophet. I'm speaking presumptuously here.

Comment: The Bible calls him a prophet, so I guess at some time he was.